# finding the longest path using bfs

Tags: c++, optimization, data-structures, queue, breadth-first-search

I am solving the [ABCPATH problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/ABCPATH) on spoj but failing due to: time limit exceeded (TLE):

I have used breadth-first search (BFS) to find the longest path but have no idea how to optimize it further. My code:

http://ideone.com/RN0QSe

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstring>
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <numeric>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <set>
using namespace std;
#define MAX 55
#define pii pair< int, int>
char grid[MAX][MAX],c,str[MAX];
int n, m;
bool inRange(int i, int j)
{
    return (i>=0 && i<n && j>=0 && j<m);
}
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    pii p;
    queue< pii > Q;
    queue<pii>Q1;
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&m);
    while(n!=0)
    {
        int d=0;
        for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            scanf("%s",str);
            for(j=0;j<m;j++)
            {
                grid[i][j]=str[j];
                //printf("%c\n",grid[i][j]);
                if(str[j]=='A')
                {
                    //printf("%d %d\n",i,j);
                    p.first=i;
                    p.second=j;
                    Q1.push(p);
                }
            }
        }
        while(!Q1.empty())
        {
            p=Q1.front();
            //printf("%d %d\n",p.first,p.second);
            Q1.pop();
            Q.push(p);
            while(!Q.empty())
            {
                p=Q.front();
                i=p.first;
                j=p.second;
                c=grid[i][j];
                Q.pop();
                if(inRange(i+1,j) && (int)grid[i+1][j]==(int)grid[i][j]+1)
                {
                    p.first=i+1;
                    p.second=j;
                    Q.push(p);
                }
                if(inRange(i-1,j) && (int)grid[i-1][j]==(int)grid[i][j]+1)
                {
                    p.first=i-1;
                    p.second=j;
                    Q.push(p);
                }
                if(inRange(i,j+1) && (int)grid[i][j+1]==(int)grid[i][j]+1)
                {
                    p.first=i;
                    p.second=j+1;
                    Q.push(p);
                }
                if(inRange(i,j-1) &&(int)grid[i][j-1]==(int)grid[i][j]+1)
                {
                    p.first=i;
                    p.second=j-1;
                    Q.push(p);
                }
                if(inRange(i-1,j-1) &&(int)grid[i-1][j-1]==(int)grid[i][j]+1)
                {
                    p.first=i-1;
                    p.second=j-1;
                    Q.push(p);
                }
                if(inRange(i+1,j+1) &&(int)grid[i+1][j+1]==(int)grid[i][j]+1)
                {
                    p.first=i+1;
                    p.second=j+1;
                    Q.push(p);
                }
                            if(inRange(i+1,j-1) &&(int)grid[i+1][j-1]==(int)grid[i][j]+1)
                            {
                                    p.first=i+1;
                                    p.second=j-1;
                                    Q.push(p);
                            }
                            if(inRange(i-1,j+1) &&(int)grid[i-1][j+1]==(int)grid[i][j]+1)
                            {
                                    p.first=i-1;
                                    p.second=j+1;
                                    Q.push(p);
                            }
            }
            if(((int)c-65)>d)
                d=((int)c-65);
        }
        printf("%d\n",d+1);
        scanf("%d %d",&n,&m);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't debug unindented code.

Comment: i am new here.What changes do i have to make?

Comment: It would be great if you could indent your code to show the structure. [Example](http://ideone.com/4islpP)

Comment: i have stored the position of 'A' in a queue and then applied bfs for each member of the queue.But this approach is giving TLE.

Comment: @MatthieuM. i hope this is what u wanted. Is it clear now?

Comment: Actually, proper indentation would be [this](http://ideone.com/Kfk5xi). Could you explain what `Q` and `Q1` store ? Do the pair of indices represent coordinates in the grid ? What is `str` ? (we don't need all, but some pointers would help.

Comment: Why are you only checking in 6 directions? Shouldn't it be 8?

Comment: @AdamBurry yeah u are right it should be 8

Comment: @MatthieuM. Q1 stores the coordinates of 'A' and Q is for traversing the grid. str is for taking the input from the user

Comment: @AdamBurry i have edited it now.now it is checking all the 8 directions

Comment: @MatthieuM. yes the pair represents the coordinates in the grid

Comment: I had fun and used a Depth First approach [here](http://ideone.com/WjrEms). Not sure it would be faster per se, but it should use less memory and memory can quickly become a bottleneck. Also, I tried to comment the code and use proper variable names to make it readable... and NOT use global variables.

Comment: @MatthieuM. u didnt debug my code.You wrote one of your own.Is bfs not applicable here?Is my approach to this problem wrong?

Comment: @RKTSP: If I had found the issue (and why you get a LTE), I would have posted an answer. I just found myself thinking about the problem and had to support people on/off for an hour so toyed with creating my own solution in the down times :) Regarding your code, apart from an ugly style (mixing C and C++, no comment, meaningless variable names) it seems to work (functionally) and just have a performance issue (LTE does not mean wrong, just too slow). Apart from the padding trick I used, one suspicion is that the breadth first approach consumes too much memory.

Comment: @MatthieuM. i finally solved it using  bfs only .just few  optimizations were needed